# Android 3.2 - SurfaceView got blacked out but reappear if the "Mini Apps Tray" visible

Tags: android, android-layout, surfaceview

I have a drawing app that works fine with Android 2.2. However, when I upgraded it to 3.2 and run in the 3.2 device, my custom SurfaceView disappears (but still take in the touch events). The strange thing is that it will reappear if I keep the Mini Apps Tray open.

Answer (score 0):

After trying to figure it out for a while, the culprit is the **setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);**.

It works like a charm after I commented it out.